# Do we use the Pronominaladverb "davon" without having a verb that requires the preposition "von" in the sentence?

Tags: pronominal-adverb

In the following sentence :

> Und eine ganz besondere Sache möchte ich euch noch zeigen, dass sind
> die Pink Ladies, die kaufen die Deutschen ganz besonders gerne, das
> ist eine Apfelsorte und ***davon*** kaufen wir jetzt 4 Stück, weil die
> nämlich besonders süß und knackig sind.

I want to know why did we use *davon* in this context.

In my knowledge, we only use *davon* when there is a verb that goes with it like for example *träumen von*, I also know that the verb *kaufen* used in the sentence does not require a preposition.

I thank you in advance for your attention.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are verbs with prepositional objects. You mentioned *träumen von*:

> (Sie *träumt* **von** einem Urlaub am Meer.)
> Sie *träumt* **davon**, am Meer Urlaub zu machen.
> **Davon** träume ich auch.

However, there are also adjectives that go with prepositions.

> Die Heizkosten sind *abhängig* **von** der Größe der Wohnung.
> Die Heizkosten sind *abhängig* **davon**, wie groß die Wohnung ist.

In this case, the adjective *abhängig* is derived from a verb and the preposition is inherited from that verb, i.e. *abhängen von*. But there are many cases of adjectives with prepositions where the adjective is not derived from a verb: *frei von*, *nett zu*, *neidisch auf*, *zuständig für*, etc.

Note that *von* in particular is also used to give the [agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_(grammar)) in a passive clause, which yields another source for *davon*.

> Das schlechte Wetter hat uns überrascht.
> Wir wurden **vom** schlechten Wetter überrascht.
> Wir wurden **davon** überrascht, wie schlecht das Wetter war.

Moving on to your particular case, *von* or a genitive are used with nouns (or, more generally, nominal phrases).

> Ich habe zu viel Suppe gekocht und einen *Teil* **der Suppe** eingefroren.
> Ich habe zu viel Suppe gekocht und einen *Teil* **davon** eingefroren.

Note that the preposition and the noun it goes with can be split.

> Ich habe zu viel Suppe gekocht. **Davon** habe ich dann einen *Teil* eingefroren.

This is what happens in your example.

> (Diese Apfelsorte kaufen die Deutschen gerne.)
> **Davon** kaufen wir jetzt *vier Stück*.
> Wir kaufen jetzt *vier Stück* **davon**.
> Wir kaufen jetzt *vier Stück* **von** dieser Sorte.

So your assumption – we only use *davon* when there is a verb that goes with it – is wrong. *Von* and *davon* also go with nouns and certain adjectives, as well as being used in the passive voice. There are also other uses I have not mentioned.
Be aware of the possibilty of *von* and *davon* being moved away from the word they belong to.

Comment: Best explaination IMO. Additionaly, we here have the difficulty that the object is semantically very close to a partitive construction: cf. _wir kaufen zwei Liter vom Rotwein_. Like we can say, _gib mir noch von den Äpfeln!_.

Answer (score 5):

Okay let’s free that original sentence from some ballast.

At its core, it’s quite simple:

> Wir kaufen vier Äpfel.

As Carsten notes, the apples are then described as being of the variety Pink Lady.

> Wir kaufen vier Äpfel von der Sorte Pink Lady.

Then we have a previous sentence that describes the buying habits of Germans.

> Die Deutschen kaufen die Apfelsorte Pink Lady sehr gerne. Wir kaufen vier Äpfel von der Sorte Pink Lady.

That’s an ugly repetition. So the second reference to the variety gets shorted to “of that” (davon), and we avoid a repeat of apple by referring to the apples as “items”.

> Die Deutschen kaufen die Apfelsorte Pink Lady sehr gerne. Wir kaufen davon vier Stück.

Answer (score 3):

You are right that there should be a *von* somewhere, and it is:

> Von dieser Apfelsorte kaufen wir vier Stück.

We will buy four *of* that kind.

Comment: Thank you ! this is really helpful but from your answer I can understand that we do not necessarily need a verb + preposition combination for adverbs such as davon or does the verb kaufen actually go with the preposition von  ?

Comment: As you can see in the answer, *kaufen* can be used with *von*. That's sufficient for using *davon* - *von* does not have to be necessary for that.

Answer (score 1):

I do not really understand why the answers are so complex. "Von" ist in many cases the equivalent of "of" and "davon" is pretty much "of that". So "davon kaufen wir 4 Stück" simply means "we are buying 4 pieces of that". Hope that simplifies the problem ;)